# Format mySQL timestamp by changing date-month and remove seconds using PHP function?

Tags: php

I echo `$istoriko['timestamp']` from mySQL and I get `2014-04-24 00:10:29`

How can I change it to

`24/04/14 (or 2014) 00:10`

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, its simple

You can set any date format now in date functions

`echo date("d/m/y",strtotime($istoriko['timestamp']));`

Comment: thank you for this, but this does not show the hours and minutes

Comment: you want the complete output `24/04/14 (or 2014) 00:10` like this ?

Comment: @Karoumpas: what MTahir posted was an example.  You can format it however you like according to the [PHP `date` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Follow functions can help you:

```
$date = '2014-04-24 00:10:29';
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i',strtotime($date));
echo $date
```